# combine two tables inserted into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a challenge and here is the scenario Table1 has year and table2
has Property type and inserting them in one table like...

table1     table2 
year       Prop_id
2001         1 
2002         1 
2001         2 
2002         2 

will be insert to 
table 3
year    Prop_id
2001         1 
2002         1 
2001         2 
2002         2

How can i attain this.. your help is highly appreciated

Comment: How do you determine which row of table2 corresponds to each row of table1?

Comment: Is there any common element that relates the two tables to each other?

Comment: @ Joe Stefanelli- no...the objective here is all Prop_id should have all the year in table 3...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into table3
select distinct table1.year, table2.prop_id  
  from table1 
 cross join table2
```

Comment: This would result in duplicate entries, for example (2001, 1) would occur twice based on the sample data given.

Comment: Also, what if there are many rows and duplicates in Jake's actual table. Then your cross join will create exponentially more rows before only grabbing the distinct ones. It would be better to grab only distinct values from each table and then cross join them

Comment: @Stephan It is not an exponential relationship and distinct is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT Year, Prop_Id FROM Table1, Table2
```